# Santiago to Iquique by bus

Tags: buses, chile, santiago-de-chile

A commenter on my blog post [about my bus ride from Santiago to Iquique](http://www.marksmayo.com/2011/03/09/24-hour-bus-ride-of-luxury-in-chile-santiago-to-iquique/) asked the following question:

> I want to travel from Santiago to Iquique by bus. Any body can tell
>   how much, how long is it and the best services too.

I figured it was worth posting on here, and asking the question.  I'll link to this question in response to his comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I am reading the [Tur-Bus](https://www.turbus.cl/wtbus/indexCompra.jsf) site wrong the prices vary between: $42 per person to $77 per person one way.

The thing is that I can't imaging myself spending 24 hours even on a most comfortable bus but then again I like my creature comforts.

Comment: if you check the blog link, it's one of the most luxurious buses I've ever been on (if you go cama class).  Despite an awful hangover, it was chilling, movie-watching and watching the scenery go by :)  All it was missing was power points and wifi ;)

Comment: Mark next time I am in Chile, I would definitly take the bus over planes again, but I would shop. I had the same experience as you when going to Chiloe, on the return I went cheap and regretted it ever since.

Comment: @MarkMayo I believe they are but I still don't see spending 24 hours on a bus. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did 16 hours next going to La Paz, and it cost me about $15.  One of the worst bus rides of my life.  So there's definitely different experiences ;)

Answer (score 1):

Santiago - Iquique takes about 22 hours by bus with the companies 
[Pullman](http://www.pullman.cl) or [Turbus](http://www.turbus.cl) and 
2 hours by plane with [Skyairline](http://www.skyairline.cl) or [LAN](http://www.lan.cl)