# Advantages of traveling from Lima to Cusco by bus vs. plane?

Tags: air-travel, buses, peru, lima

Do you think it makes sense to fly rather than travel by bus in terms of time/money? Or perhaps traveling by bus is not that bad?

Also, I've been told that landing in Cusco is quite spectacular and I was thinking to save some time.

Could someone please clarify the pros/cons of travelling there by road vs by air?

Comment: Note that due to the altitude difference, travelling to Cusco in one journey may be dangerous or at least uncomfortable. During our visit they took the time to get there, visiting other sites, in order to get used to the height. And because it is a beautiful country with lots to see it is not a burden at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Bus ride from Lima to Cuzco](http://www.go2peru.travel/peru_bus/buses_from_to_cuzco.htm) is **20 to 21 hours** depending on the company, costing from **$65 for one-way ticket**. And it's also mainly less-than-safe mountain road.

[Flight from Lima to Cuzco](http://www.go2peru.travel/peru_flights/flights_from_to_cuzco.htm) is **1h10m** to 1h25m and you can get  ticket as cheap as **$175 for round-trip**.

Comment: *IMHO the choice is quite obvious.*  Not really.

Comment: @Karlson: Isn't it? Why would you spend 42 hours on the road? Especially given that these are one of most dangerous roads of the world.

Comment: Because I might want to, since it's one of the most dangerous roads in the world.  Because I don't trust the airlines I have to fly to get there.  And the last but not least Why Not?  OP gives no indication of personal preferences just asking for opinion.  And while I would fly instead of taking a bus I am not going to presume that someone else would prefer the same.

Comment: @vartec For the same reason a lot of travellers take the bus (or terrestrial transportation): to see what is around. Maybe you just want to visit Cusco, some would want to visit Peru.

Comment: Take a look at these 2 questions. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9120/la-paz-to-santiago-by-bus, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5533/santiago-to-iquique-by-bus

Comment: @Vince: I wouldn't call spending 42 hours in a bus more "visting Peru" than spending these two days somewhere else, like let's say Salinas and Lake Titicaca. But you're right, that's just my opinion.

Comment: @vartec Thanks for the answer. Where did you find the flight price 175$ for round-trip. Checking on skyscanner.com I can only find tickets for 135 one-way.

Comment: @Patrick Check the link in the answer.

Comment: @Karlson In the website, I could only find 150$ one-way flights and around 200$ flights all-around. I'm interested in one-way flights from Lima to Cusco.

Comment: @Patrick Look at Star Peru airline.  Changing dates may also change prices.  Plus taxes and fees may not be included.

Comment: @Karlson Did you manage to change the flight day on the website ? Because I didn't

Comment: @Patrick You can change it when you click Book.

Comment: @Karlson Thanks. It seems that the prices don't change depending on the date. I couldn't find an one-way flight cheaper than 150$

Comment: Check Peruvian Airlines prices too. Note that LAN charges non-locals a higher rate than international travelers whereas Peruvian Airlines and Star Peru do not. The same ticket on LAN could be $300 for foreigners...

Answer (score 10):

As someone who's done it, I like the bus.  Of course, there are pros and cons of each.

**Bus**

*Pros*: A bus is cheaper, you get to see more of the countryside, interact with more people. You get breaks, get good seats (they have business class buses!), and you can stop off at places on the way.  We stopped in Arequipa to go to the Colca Canyon, and in Nazca for a few hours to see the Nazca Lines.

*Cons*: It takes a long time. Some legs in the desert can be dull.  Some people argue that it's a dangerous road, but I'd say that's maybe only in the mountains - the coastal road from Nazca to Lima is modern and high quality.

**Plane**

*Pros*: You get there faster. You get an aerial view.  Save time.

*Cons*: It's more expensive.  You will not have a gradual introduction to the altitude, and may as a result get a bit of a shock when you step off the plane - it can be quite hard the first few days.  You're stuck in a cramped economy class seat. You don't get to interact with many people.

Hopefully that helps.  Personally, even though I bused last time, if I had the time, I'd bus again.  I disagree with @vartec - the choice is not obvious, and I loved the bus trip.  But you must make that decision yourself, of course :)

Comment: I agree with Mark. If you want to visit and experience Peru, take the bus. If you just want to visit Machu Picchu, then fly. I met several people in Cusco that flew in and had problem with the altitude. Taking the bus does not mean you wont have any problems with it but its a bit less likely. If you are short on time, I think it's better to spend a day on a bus and be okay than flying and may be sick for days.

Comment: The bus is rather dangerous because of the accidents, however if you travel with a good company it is a great trip, you will get to visit Arequipa and Ica, and some of the tours do a stop to check the town.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to see country is via bus and the first class buses have bed like seats and you can see Nazca lines along the way and fly back via TACA Airlines to Lima.  That does lessen chance of altitude sickness. And you will see spectacular scenery via air on way back. So romantic - the snow tipped Andes piercing the clouds.